# Problems with File I/o when porting old 'C' libraries from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: c, file-io, 32bit-64bit

I have really old 'c' code that uses read to read a binary file.  Here is a sample:

```
uint MyReadFunc(int _FileHandle, char *DstBuf, uint BufLen)
{  
    return (read( _FileHandle, DstBuf, BufLen));
}
```

For 64bit OS - char * will be 64 bits but the  BufLen is only 32 bits and the returned value are only 32 bits.

Its not an option to change this to .NET - I have .NET versions, but I need this old library converted also.

Can someone please tell me what I need to use to do File i/o on 64 bit OS (using 'C' code)

Comment: Are the different sizes causing problems? Because I can't see any reason they would.

Comment: What kind of error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

Use `size_t`, not `uint`.

Comment: You mean `ssize_t`, since `read` can return `-1`.  Assuming POSIX `read` of course.

Comment: Yes, the return type should be `ssize_t`. I had missed that; I meant that `BufLen` should be a `size_t`.

Comment: I am using Windows Vista,  Visual Studio 2005 - the prototype for read is:
int read(int fileHandle, void * buffer, unsigned int buffSize)
Not size_t - I agree it "should" be size_t, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're conflating two things: size of a pointer and the extent of the memory it points to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about char* being 64-bits - the pointer itself will be 64-bit, yes, but the actual value is still a character array, unless I'm missing something?  (I'm not a brilliant C programmer.)

The length argument to read() is size_t, not int, which on a 64-bit system should be 64-bit not 32.  Also the return value is a ssize_t, not int, which will also be 64-bit so you should be covered if you just change your function definition to return ssize_t, and take size_t instead of the ints.

Comment: I am using Windows Vista,  Visual Studio 2005 - the prototype for read is:
int read(int fileHandle, void * buffer, unsigned int buffSize)
Not size_t - I agree it "should" be size_t, but it isn't.